# Determing whether number is prime in Ruby

Tags: ruby, each, primes

I'm trying to write a method that returns true or false based on whether the integer being evaluated is prime or not. The below code is something I've cobbled together based on reading Wikipedia articles, previous stackoverflow answers, etc. Currently the program returns true for prime numbers, but doesn't return false. I want to do this without using any built-in functions. How should I fix this?

```
def prime?(integer)
 (2..integer - 1).each do |x|
  if (integer % x) == 0
   return false
  else
   return true
  end
end
end
```

Comment: Note: `each`, `-`, `%` and `==` are built-in functions. :P

Comment: @amadan - don't be pedantic; you know @TiantianShi is referring to libraries like `Prime`.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a logic problem. The program returns true for any number that's not divisible by 2. So, just put the `return true` statement after the loop has been executed completely.

```
def prime?(integer)
    return false if integer < 2
    (2..integer - 1).each do |x|
        if (integer % x) == 0
            return false
        end
    end
    true
end
```

Comment: It looks like this method is still not returning false if it isn't a prime number...is there also a logic issue with my prime check?

Comment: I think it is not just not working for the case of 1 and 0

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, starting out with a variable set to true.

```
def prime?(integer)
  (2..integer - 1).each {|x| return false if (integer % x) == 0 }
  true
end
```

Comment: `val` can be set to `false` then back to `true`. You simply want to return `false` if a factor between `2` and `integer-1` is found. If there is no such factor, return `true`. You don't need the variable `val`.

Comment: Thank you, feedback is well received.